# Add additional directories to ack.vim

Tags: vim, rvm, ack

Using vim-rvm and ack.vim, I would like to be able to search through the current path (set by NERDTree) and through the gem directory (set by RVM command from vim.rvm).

I know that ack allows to search through multiple directories

```
 ack controller dir1 dir2
```

However, is there a way to append gem directory to ack.vim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write a custom command (e.g. `:AckMore`) or redefine the `:Ack` command to include additional paths. Sketch (not working; I don't use those plugins):

```
:command! -nargs=* AckMore execute 'Ack' <q-args> g:gem_directory
```

Comment: thanks, that helps. is there a way to reference the original path? basically i'm trying to have a search across my codebase and the gem directory.